# Doctrine Error: "An exception occured in driver (...)"

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am new at Simphony. The tutorial that I am following to get started with, tell me to do, on my Terminal, this command:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:entity
```

When I execute the command, this error occurs:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                     
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]               
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  

[PDOException]                                    
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I have searched and I did not find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you don't have the database created, try to create it with
    app/console doctrine:database:create

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It outputs the same error.

Comment: Is your database server up and running?

Comment: Sorry I am new with this, how can I check it?

Comment: http://www.ewhathow.com/2013/09/how-to-check-if-mysql-server-is-running-on-linux/ or for windows https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.1/en/windows-testing.html

Comment: I found this for Mac OS http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55214/whats-the-services-running-processes-manager-in-mac-os-x/55220

Comment: I did not have MySQL Server installed. Sorry for that.